# Want to track mobile users location

Tags: php, jquery, mobile

i am  working on one php project, which have deals section. under deals listing, we are tracking users ip address.

we are using API to  find geo location from ip address. then we are calculating distance between user and the store address.

this is working fine on desktop computers. but its not working properly for mobile devices.

is there any another option to track geo location of mobile users.

thanks in advanced.

Comment: `"but its not working properly for mobile devices"` is **not** a good description of the problem. Please supply the related code **or** elaborate on the error to be helped further.

Comment: @Darren for desktop computers he find the user location by its IP. but how to find location of user if user using site from his mobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Geolocation using HTML5 :

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

Here you can get coordinates of a place. Find coordinates of your store's location and write a function to get distance between two coordinates.